# Basing your project on another project

Tags: git

I am trying to base my project `A` on a 3rd party project `B`. `A` will change 2 files of `B` and add a few more. Eventually, I want to get a new version of `B` from the original repo and combine it with `A`, keeping all my changes to it.

I tried to do this by making a branch `source` where I put in the vanilla `B` and all future versions of it. Then merge it with `master` and resolve the merge conflicts of those 2 files mentioned above manually and everything should be fine, or so I thought. Playing around with it, I made two different `README.md` files for each branch, and after a merge of `source` into `master`, I found that the `README.md` of `source` was also changed. Apparently I am fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Considering how common this must be, there gotta be an easy and git-beginner friendly way to do this? When I google for it, all I find is how to do pull requests and submit them to the original repo, but I do not plan to contribute to `B`, but make my own version of it.

So, just to be clear, my question is not directly how to make my attempt work, but how to archieve what I described in the first paragraph.

Comment: The http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is a better place to find out about "Best Practices" of anything, as practices are often questionable.

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info). Also your site recommendation doesn't look compelling, see [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go)

Comment: @gnat I agree regarding cross-posting - it is not desired to say the least. However, previously this question was titled "Best practices for basing (...)" and whenever practices (for example "clean code" questions) are involved, it is suggested to move discussion to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz prior title didn't help in making it better fit over there I'm afraid, see [Making “best practices” questions more palatable: how to ask a “best practice” question that is acceptable to the community?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7091/31260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to resolve the problem you are having. Simplest one would be to follow these steps:

1. Make a `fork` of repository `B`.
2. Clone forked repository to your local machine.
3. On your local machine, add a second remote to your current repository: `git remote add upstream git@github.com:USERNAME/PROJECT_B_REPOSITORY.git`
4. From time to time pull changes from remote B to your local repository `git pull upstream` resolve conflicts and push to `origin` (which is project `A` remote).

Comment: Something I found out which other git-beginners might find handy to know up front when considering to choose this method: You don't need to delete the files of `B` you don't need for your project `A` again after pulling in the new version of `B`. Git got brains.